# Excel Match not returning correct row number

Tags: excel-formula, excel-match

As you can see from the image my match formula is returning the value of 10. I expected it to return 7, as it is 7 rows down.

Why is this happening? [Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjkDB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the "Match Type" criteria to Exact by inserting a zero : =MATCH(F15, F9:F20,0).

Comment: @bensd : You asked why---Because your search entries contained text along with numbers, the cells are considered "text" cells.With text cells, MATCH needs to use an "Exact" match as the criteria. That is the third criteria, "0",which you omitted. That made it default to criteria "1".